# C# Write File From Azure Function to SharePoint On-Prem

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to write C# code in an Azure Function running in the Azure cloud to move files to and from an instance of SharePoint on-premises ?  I have heard that to do this I require some sort of data gateway or connector of some sort to be in place.

Any guidance much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you please refer this [Blog](https://www.itprotoday.com/file-sharing-and-management/using-azure-functions-within-sharepoint) ,Let us know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be possible but there's lots of factors to take into account with regards to your environment and how it is configured from a network perspective.

You are able to run Azure Functions within your on-premises environment. You can see some of the hybrid scenarios here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/azure-functions-hybrid#running-azure-functions-on-premises

There's also App Service Hybrid Connections which allow you to reach on-premises infrastructure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

There's a devblogs post with a scenario you can read also:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/